# Android: calling a method from a Service to an Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a simple question to solve, but I am not sure how to do it.

I have a class that extends Service that runs a thread looking for a TCP connection. If one comes in, it read an input message.

If the input message is "START", I start an activity, in this fashion:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), VoIPCall.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
dialogIntent.putExtra("inetAddress", clientSocket.getInetAddress());
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

While this activity is running, the Service keeps running. At some point I may reserve a "STOP". I would like to call a method in the previously created Activity but I am not sure how to interact with it.

I do not want to use a static method. How can I please do that?

Thank you very much,

EDIT: I changed my code to this:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent("com.voip.rudy.START_CALL");
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
dialogIntent.putExtra("inetAddress", clientSocket.getInetAddress());
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

And in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".VoIPCall">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.voip.rudy.START_CALL" />
        <action android:name="com.voip.rudy.STOP_CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> was required to avoid having it crash.
```

EDIT:

The solution given has fixed my issue but I wanted to actually act on member variables on that class, that are previously initialized. Say I call the constructor, then I would like to go back into this activity and act on the member variables.

The member variables are not initialized when I call one action after another, it seems to create a new activity somehow. Would there be anyway to act on the same activity, and keep the objects intact please?

James

Comment: Your best bet is probably sending a broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flags to your intent and call startActivity with a new action or a special extra that can identify the intent.

In the activity, write a method called :

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
}
```

call this from onCreate (or onResume) using:

```
handleIntent(getIntent());
```

and also write:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically, I just specify two actions, one would be the method, the other one is the "normal constructor"? onCreate should just do handleIntent() and the rest of the code (method + constructor) should be in handleIntent, where I do something like: intent.getAction().equals()... right? Trying to do it this way, thank you.

Comment: I've implemented but I am getting an issue, not sure why the onCreate does not get executed. I have posted an EDIT in my main post with the error as well. Thank you.

Comment: This works really well. I am having a little issue though, but I think it's because I was not precise. I have some member variables declared in my activity class. When using your method, the member variables are not initialized when I call one action after another, it seems to create a new one. Would there be anyway to act on the same activity, and keep the objects intact please?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a little rushed and didn't explain fully. Android can always kill your activity, but is less likely to kill your service. The only way I know of to reliably keep the service running is for it to call startForeground(). In light of this, your activity needs to be able to recreate itself after having been killed so should not store important long lived state. If the activity was not killed, the flags on the intent will save you from creating a second instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you are saying. If you don't mind, I will explain what I am doing. There is a Service class that always look for TCP packets. If a "START_CALL" arrives, it starts an Activity with some button (to end a call) and 2 threads: they use the AudioTrack and AudioRecord to play/save sound, and receive/send them through UDP. When the service class receives a "STOP_CALL", I would like to call a method in this same Activity to call stop() and release() on the AudioTrack/AudioRecord object, and close the sockets.

Comment: I've implemented your method, but it is creating a new Activity for STOP_CALL, as I call "startActivity()" with the intent. Could you please tell me how I can call a method in this former activity rather than making a new one, or is my design flawed, and in this case, do you please have any suggestions?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it, really depends on the overall structure of your application.  All can work.  Off the top of my head these are the methods that come to mind

1) Create a custom intent and have the activity or service react to it when the otehr sends it
2) Instead of the service, setup the logic looking for the tcp connection as an async task within the dialog activity,  when you have the tcp connection you could pass it off to the service to do its work
3) Take a look at the local service and remote service SDK examples and use the callback code as the basis for passing data back to the activity.  You can also call through the interface back to the service.
4) Maybe even setup a broadcast receiver 'architecture'.  This has the advantage of decoupling the user activity from the service entirely. You could put some of your application logic in a service in another process, or even in a process that runs at device boot.

Comment: Your welcome.  There are lots of examples of these things in the SDK, but I can throw up a code snippet if you need it.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot Jeff, I really appreciate it. Well, unfortunately, my problem is not completely fixed, because the solution I implemented makes a new activity (In the comment above I described my issue a little bit more). Would any of your solutions fix my issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I think any of the techniques would work.  I'm guessing that the behavior you are seeing is related to the lifecycle of the activities within android and you might need to move some of your processing to the onResume/onPause or onStart/onStop methods.   If you you find that your activity onCreate is not being called, but you now your activity is active, it might jsut be that an activity instance from a previous invocation is still alive in the system. If so, it is possible that the OS is using that instead of the new activity that you want.  The best way to see if this is a problem is to put some "Log.d" calls at the beginning and end of all of the activity methods that you override.  You will be able to tell what is happening by watching logcat.  The technique that you use may also be dependent on how synchronous you want the activity's reaction to be with the TCP event.  If you want completely async you can go with a standard broadcast, or a service callback with a message send. If you want synchronous then do it with a service callback.  In case you haven't seen it this SDK link has a pretty good description of the activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html